# Navbar fixa após segunda section

Tags: jquery, css3

O código está quebrando aqui no stackflow, mas enfim, estou tentando fazer a navbar rolar com a página até o inicio da segunda seção onde ela fica fixa, porém não estou conseguindo, mesmo que no exemplo abaixo esteja meio quebrado, o problema da barra no site é o mesmo, não está fazendo aparecer fixa no topo.

http://johnsburger.com.br/wxsite31/johnsburger/

```js
var isFixed = false;

$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  var navbar = $(".navbar");
  var heroSectionHeight = $(".fullscreen").height();

  // Set fixed
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= heroSectionHeight && !isFixed) {
    isFixed = true;
    navbar.hide().addClass(".navbar-fixed-top").slideDown(375);
  }

  // Set static
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < heroSectionHeight && isFixed) {
    isFixed = false;
    navbar.slideUp(375, function() {
      navbar.removeClass(".navbar-fixed-top").show();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
@import 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato';

.navbar {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 4px -100px 0 63px;
  font-size: 13px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav li a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  z-index: 99999;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 19.5px;
  padding-bottom: 19.5px;
  /*-webkit-transition: 0.1s; /* Safari */
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #FFBA53;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.static-nav {
  position: static;
}

.fixed-nav {
  position: fixed;
}

.navbar-default,
.navbar-inverse {
  border: 0;
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar>.container .navbar-brand,
.navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #0d33b9;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #811b9a;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1A242F;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
}

section {
  padding: 120px 0;
}

section h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  section {
    padding: 75px 0;
  }
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.space {
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 17px;
}

#navcontainer .container {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.underline:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

#introduction p {
  color: #4C4C4C;
  position: relative;
  left: 65px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.infos {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 55px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: right;
}

.subtitlea {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.subtitleb {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.subtitlec {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.titlea {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #4C4C4C;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.titleb {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #4C4C4C;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.titlec {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #4C4C4C;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

#banner {
  padding: 25px 0;
}

#owl-demo .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.owl-dots {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  bottom: 44px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
  width: 2.4rem;
  height: 2.4rem;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

.title2 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1.7rem -7.0rem 0 0;
  float: right;
  width: 140px;
  height: 42px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#introduction {
  background-image: url(http://johnsburger.com.br/wxsite31/johnsburger/img/capa.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  /* width: 100%; */
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.blurbox {
  background-image: url("http://johnsburger.com.br/wxsite31/johnsburger/img/");
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffffa3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

#introduction img {
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
}

#introduction h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 65px;
}

.sub {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 500;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 9px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  color: #4C4C4C;
}

.box-info {
  padding-right: 73px;
  padding-top: 65px;
}

.informaçao {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 54px;
}

.item {
  width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="fullscreen">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div id="navcontainer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <!-- Toggle Button -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainnav-navbar-collapse">
        MENU <span class="fa fa-bars color-white"></span>
       </button>
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#introduction"></a><img class="svg1" src="http://johnsburger.com.br/wxsite31/johnsburger/img/logo.svg"></a>
          </div>
          <!-- Navigation Links -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainnav-navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="underline page-scroll">
                <a href="#burger">Burgers</a>
              </li>
              <li class="underline page-scroll">
                <a href="#acompanhamentos">Acompanhamentos</a>
              </li>
              <li class="underline page-scroll">
                <a href="#bebidas">Bebidas</a>
              </li>
              <li class="underline page-scroll">
                <a href="#sobremesas">Sobremesas</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn trigger btn-light"><img class="space" src="img/profile.png"> Login</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
<section id="introduction" class="fullscreen">

  <div class="blurbox">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://johnsburger.com.br/wxsite31/johnsburger/img/logog.png">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2">
          <h1>JOHN'S BURGER DELIVERY</h1>
          <p class="pmobile">Rua Hermógenes Prazeres, 371 - Centro - Biguaçu / SC</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="box-info">
              <div class="informaçao">
                <span class="titlec">Atendimento:</span><br/>
                <span class="subtitlec">18h30 às 23h30</span>
                <h4 class="h4mobile">ABERTO ATÉ AS 23h30</h4>
              </div>


              <div class="informaçao">
                <span class="titleb">Taxa de entrega:</span><br/>
                <span class="subtitleb">A partir de R$ 0,00</span>
              </div>

              <div class="informaçao">
                <span class="titlea">Tempo de entrega:</span><br/>
                <span class="subtitlea">35 a 40 minutos</span>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">
        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

          <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://johnsburger.com.br/wxsite31/johnsburger/img/banner.png"></div>
          <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://johnsburger.com.br/wxsite31/johnsburger/img/banner2.png"></div>
          <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://johnsburger.com.br/wxsite31/johnsburger/img/banner3.png"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Cara não entendi direito, vc quer que a barra suma ao rolar pela sessão 1 nas que volte a aparecer e fique fixa a partir da sessão 2 é isso?

Comment: Exatamente, ela nunca sera fixa na primeira section, apenas a partir da segunda

Answer (score 0):

Ok, averiguei a situação aqui rapidamente no link fornecido e já enxergo um problema. Você precisa atualizar o z-index da sua navbar fixa, caso contrário ela ficará por baixo do conteúdo do site.

O seu código javascript também não está funcionando corretamente. Quando o scroll ocorre, ele tenta modificar a classe do nav, mas sem sucesso, e logo volta para o padrão estático.

Comment: Obrigado, e como poderia resolver esse problema do scroll que nao aplica a class?

Comment: @EduStadler, você precisa desenvolver o seu código Javascript para que não haja falhas. Infelizmente eu não posso lhe ajudar muito com essa questão